# Auto rig a pre existing weighted armature?

Tags: rigging

Anyone know of any addons or a way to Auto rig a pre existing weighted armature? I am using daz3d models and i want to add a rig to the allready weighted bones that come with the character. Human ik in maya is the closest thing i have found so far. It would seem like rigify would have this feature but i havent been able to find anything that doesnt involve writing python yourself.

Comment: Does daz3d allow the export of fbx or collada models? If so, which one did you use? Both of them can be imported into Blender with varying degrees of success depending on the exporter of the source program.

Comment: Yes...i used collada although some limited success with fbx. Im looking to create a rig and attach it to the skeleton that comes with the model. Maybe have to brush up on python if there isnt something available allready